# When using SwipeRefreshLayout, I can see previous fragment(s) below while swiping down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have `SwipeRefreshLayout` implemented in one of my fragments that contains a list view.  I have it fully working, the items refresh as I desire when I swipe down.

However, sometimes I can see another previously-visited fragment "below" the current fragment.  It is revealed by the swipe down.

What's the crux of the issue here?

Comment: Try using replace() method on FragmentManager when inflate fragment, instead of add(). can u attach some code?

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem just now, and was able to solve it by simply wrapping the SwipRefreshLayout in a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have removed the windowBackground and what you are seeing is a leftover in the memory in an area that is not drawed at all (not even a background).